# Luracast Restler Validator returns warning about expecting string, getting array

Tags: php, json, api, patch, restler

I'm sending the following json: `{"name":"New event"}`

to a PATCH handler: `function patch($id, $request_data = NULL)`

but am getting the following warning: `Warning:  strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /public_html/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Data/Validator.php on line 115`

The source at that line is:

```
switch ($info->type) {
    ...
    case 'string' :
       $r = strlen($input);
```

So I added some code to the first line of Validator.validate() see what it thinks the variables are:

```
print("$input: $info->type\n");
```

and I get this:

```
1: int
Array: string
```

So it thinks the array is a string. It is still able to continue and process the request, but it returns this warning as the response instead of something valid I can process.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For now I have added this to Validator.php:

`if (is_array($input)) $info->type = "array";`

to the top of the validate function and it is fixing the problem, but I'm not sure if that is the best approach.

Comment: changing the $info->type in Validator class is not the right way. Are you using any php doc comments for the parse method? if so, please add it to the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version (Restler 3 RC4) in v3 branch fixes this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too， but that's because I gave `param` wrong type.

For example

```
@param string $request_data
```

change type

```
 string to mixed
```

the problem will be solved.